# Dividing a ThreadPool class into component classes to reduce/isolate complexity

Tags: c++, complexity

I have a `ThreadPool` class which has grown to a point where it is becoming difficult to keep all of this unit of work in mind. It is also becoming harder to read. For this reason I would like to break this class into component classes.

First of all here is the class header with comments:

```
//ThreadPool.h

#ifndef THREADPOOL_H
#define THREADPOOL_H

#define doNothing()

#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

typedef std::function< void() > voidFunctionType;  

class ThreadPool{

 public:
  ThreadPool(unsigned int desiredThreadCount);
  ~ThreadPool();

  //Functions Affecting ThreadPool
  //Function used by threads to submit work to ThreadPool
  void workSubmit(voidFunctionType functionPointer);
  //Function used by threads to take work from ThreadPool
  voidFunctionType takeTask(void);
  //Function which returns the number of work in the queue
  unsigned int workCount(void);
  //Function which 
  bool isWorkAvailable(void);

  //Functions Affecting Thread Availability.
  //Increments availableThreads variable which indicates number of threads available
  void incThreadAvailability(void);
  //Decrements availableThreads variable which indicates number of treads available
  void decThreadAvailability(void);
  //Returns availableThreads variable which indicates number of threads available
  unsigned int getThreadAvailability(void);
  //Function returns total number of threads generated
  unsigned int getThreadNum(void);

  //Functions Affecting Threads
  //Checks to see if work is available, if work is not available thread is put to sleep
  //If work is available thread processes work. 
  void threadSleepUntillWorkAvail(void);

 private:
  // Number of threads generated
  unsigned int numberOfThreads;

  //Vector of threads
  std::vector<std::thread> workers;

  // Number of threads available to process work
  unsigned int availableThreads;
  // Mutex for the availableThreads variable
  std::mutex threadAvailabilityLock;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> threadAvailabilityLockUnique;

  //Workqueue to track work
  std::queue< std::function< void()> > workQueue;
  //WorkSubmissionLock mutex is used to lock submission of work only
  std::mutex workSubmissionLock;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> workSubmissionLockUnique;
  std::condition_variable workSubmissionCondition;
  //WorkQueueLock mutex is used to lock all access points to the queue it self
  std::mutex workQueueLock;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> workQueueLockUnique;
  std::condition_variable workQueueCondition;

  //Private Member Functions
  //workAccept is used within workSubmit. This function is used to load the workQueue with the
  //Accepted work. 
  void workAccept(voidFunctionType functionPointer);

  //Operators
  //Function executed by threads.
  void operator()(void); 
};
#endif
```

I have tried creating a thread component class, however it was highly coupled with the ThreadPool class and the only value it provided was a single routine which was the main routine the threads executed. So I replaced this class with the function method operator within the threadpool class.

Other than the thread class component I am unsure if I can extract out any other single responsibility from this class.

Note:

1. I am aware of a resource deadlock problem when 3 or more threads are created, I do not want this issue to be the focal point.
2. I do not think the implementation is relevant to the question, however, it can be viewed [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/VT123/eenj9/threadpool-implementation).

Comment: As an aside, it appears that methods such as `workCount()` should be declared `const` - you might need to make the mutex `mutable` (but that's reasonable, not being logical state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are way too many member variables:

```
unsigned int numberOfThreads;
std::vector<std::thread> workers;
unsigned int availableThreads;
```

Can you not find the number of threads with `workers.size()`. What's the difference between `number of Threads` and `Available Threads` and more importantly why do you need to know!

You have three mutex's and two condition variables! Why? Also why are you putting the `unique_lock` as a member of the class! That would make them hard to use in a shared context.

Normally I would expect to see:

```
//In class:
    std::mutex               lock;
    std::condition_variable  sync;

//Adding Stuff Function:
    std::lock_guard   guard(lock);
    queue.push(item);
    sync.notify();

//Taking stuff from Queue
    std::lock_guard   guard(lock);
    sync.wait(guard, [queue](){!queue.empty();});
    if (!queue.empty()) {
        result = queue.pop();
    }
```

The only method that should be public on that class is adding a new job. All other methods are private members.

This is what mine would look like this:

```
class WorkQueue
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::thread>            threads;
        std::deque<std::function<void()>>   queue;
        std::mutex                          lock;
        std::condition_variable             sync;
        bool                                finished;

        std::function<void()> getWork();
        void work();
    public:
        WorkQueue(int threadCount);
        ~WorkQueue();
        template<typename F>
        void addWork(F&& func);
};
```